# Android studio Picasso loader is not working after the first time I run the app

Tags: android, bitmap, background, android-relativelayout, picasso

I use these lines of code(I am using the picasso library) for downloading an image and loading it into the background of my RelativeLayout.

```
Target target = new Target() {
 @Override
 public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
  relative_layout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap));
  }
 @Override
 public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
 relative_layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blolo);
 }
 @Override
public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
 relative_layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blolo);
}
 };
Picasso.with(this)
 .load("http://i.imgur.com/D3IBDDS.jpg")
 .into(target);
```

The thing is that when I run the app with my emulator for the first time everything works fine. The problem is that the next time I run the app it never works, the background never changes. I can assure you that I do not change anything in the code.I just press run again the app.However, if I change a single line of code, for example I make some comments e.g.: //blah blah and if I press run it works again even though the comments have no functionality. And like before if I press again run the app without making any change in the code the background never changes. Is there any bug or am I haunted?

***EDIT:*** after some logchat outputs I discovered that the first time I run the app, the logchat shows that onBitmapLoaded() runs and everything works fine. The other times I run the app logchat shows that  onPrepareLoad() runs and sets the background to my placeholder because of this problem **W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the answer. I thought by the coding I have done already the Target object would not be considered as garbage. Unfortunately I was wrong and I had to add this line of code to make it stable and correct. I add it here for others who have the same problem as me:

```
relative_layout.setTag(target);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you have Instant Run disabled, as this is known to cause issues with code not refreshing properly.

If you're still facing the issue, go to `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...` and then restart Android Studio.

Comment: Nope, I did both of them. The first one is not working at all. And the second one works only for the first time running the app.

Answer (score 0):

Use AQuery this best one to fetch/download image from **URL** at run time

**app level gradle entry**
**compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.24.**3'

How to use:

```
ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    AQuery aQuery = new AQuery(img);

    aQuery.id(img).image("http://i.imgur.com/D3IBDDS.jpg",true, true);
```

In second argument two boolean values stands for File cache and Memory Cache, if your image view use same **URL** second time then no download again and again it will use same image from cache.

1. Fast
2. Simple
3. easy to use
4. It has much feature like memory cache and file cache, default image in no server response, you can use progress Bar until image takes time to download, quick reflection in ListView and RecyclerView.

Comment: Well I do not want to download a pic for an imageview. Picasso works perfect with picasso for me. I want to download a pic and set it as a background to the RelativeLayout. In this case I have to download the pic and put it in a bitmapDrawable as I do on the lines of code above. This is the reason I need picasso.